# Apache HTTPS to Tomcat http connectivity not working

Tags: apache, tomcat, ssl

I have 2 linux instances on AWS , a webserver that has apache running on it and the other has tomcat running it.
The website on apache is configured to process requests over https and internally the requests go to tomcat over http.

Things i have done so far w.r.t to ssl,

1) created self signed certificate on the apache server.

2) installed and enabled mod_ssl modules in my httpd.conf file

3) mapped my domain to required document root and also to required proxy pass settings in virtual hosts

the website is accessible over https but as soon as you click a link that makes a backend call to tomcat , it fails. I have looked through the net and have played around with all possible config changes not sure what is the issue.

My VirtualHost settings....

```html
Listen 443
SSLCipherSuite HIGH:MEDIUM:!MD5:!RC4
SSLProxyCipherSuite HIGH:MEDIUM:!MD5:!RC4
SSLHonorCipherOrder on 
SSLProtocol all -SSLv3
SSLProxyProtocol all -SSLv3
SSLPassPhraseDialog  builtin
SSLSessionCache        "shmcb:/opt/apache24/logs/ssl_scache(512000)"
SSLSessionCacheTimeout  300

<VirtualHost _default_:443>

DocumentRoot "/opt/testapp/ui"
ServerName app.dev.testapp.dom.com

ErrorLog "/opt/testapp/logs/error_log"
TransferLog "/opt/testapp/logs/access_log"

SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile "/opt/testapp/certificate/testapi.crt"
SSLCertificateKeyFile "/opt/testapp/certificate/testapi.key"

<FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
</FilesMatch>
<Directory "/opt/apache24/cgi-bin">
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
</Directory>

BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-5]" \
         nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
         downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0

CustomLog "/opt/apache24/logs/ssl_request_log" \
          "%t %h %{SSL_PROTOCOL}x %{SSL_CIPHER}x \"%r\" %b"


</VirtualHost>                                  


<VirtualHost _default_:443>

ServerName api.dev.testapp.dom.com
ErrorLog "/opt/testapp/logs/error_log"
TransferLog "/opt/testapp/logs/access_log"

SSLEngine on
SSLProxyEngine on

ProxyPass / http://ec2-100-100-100-100.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8080/testapi/
ProxyPassReverse / http://ec2-100-100-100-100.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8080/testapi/

SSLCertificateFile "/opt/testapp/certificate/testapi.crt"
SSLCertificateKeyFile "/opt/testapp/certificate/testapi.key"

<FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
</FilesMatch>
<Directory "/opt/apache24/cgi-bin">
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
</Directory>

BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-5]" \
         nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
         downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0

CustomLog "/opt/apache24/logs/ssl_request_log" \
          "%t %h %{SSL_PROTOCOL}x %{SSL_CIPHER}x \"%r\" %b"

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Could you please check for an errors in logs, request or response? 
As first glanvce it may be caused by [same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy), but we need some more information.

Comment: I am continuing to debug and running the http and https versions side by side. In the browser's debug window I can see in http version of the site the api calls to tomcat are going through but for https the backend request is not even generated. Not sure what is happening

Comment: Kind of got it working , when looking in detail to responses in the browser's debug window it showed that the self signed certificate is invalid , I added the certificate to local store and it started working.